# When I try to search for a site in duckduckgo it brings me to a blank white page

Tags: help

I just redownloaded TOR for the first time in a while so im relearning it. I tried to go to google just to try it out and see if it would work. Duckduckgo sent me to a blank white page with a search bar at the top it has done this with every website Ive tried except the support site.

Comment: Can you share the specific addresses/URLs that don't work for you?

Comment: Hang on! Can we clarify the question? When you say “every website Ive tried”, do you actually mean “every *search term* I’ve tried”? And what exactly is this “support site” that works where everything else fails?